# Integrating Opbeat with Totaljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, total.js

I would like to use Opbeat with Totaljs.
Do you have an idea how to use this tool with Total?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i haven't tried i believe the way to use Opbeat in Total.js is as follows

Place bellow code above `require('total.js').http(....)` or basicly at the very top of the file where this line `require('total.js').http(....)` is used.

```
// globally available OPBEAT can be used throughout the application
global.OPBEAT = require('opbeat').start({
  // see documentations for more info
  appId: '<app id>',
  organizationId: '<org id>',
  secretToken: '<token>'
});

require('total.js').http(....);
```

for logging errors or whatever you want you can use any of [framework events](https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#api~Framework~F.on('cache-expire'))

but since the framework doesn't emit event in case of error the easiest you can do is to overwrite bellow function, place the code bellow in some definition file

```
Framework.prototype.onError = function(err, name, uri) {

    OPBEAT.captureError(err);

    // original code can be left as is
    console.log('======= ' + (new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) + ': ' + (name ? name + ' ---> ' : '') + err.toString() + (uri ? ' (' + parser.format(uri) + ')' : ''), err.stack);
    return this;
};
```

**EDIT**

one of these may be needed for showing the URL in Opbeat dashboard

```
F.on('request', function(req, res) {

    OPBEAT.setTransactionName(req.method + ' ' + req.url);

});

F.on( 'controller', function( controller, name ) {

  OPBEAT.setTransactionName(controller.route.method + ' ' + controller.route.url);

});
```